# c# code for mobile app that sends sos message to selected contacts

Tags: c#, mobile-application, sos

I am just a beginner in c# and I need your help regarding this project.I need some help reg How to send a SOS message to selected contacts from my mobile phone to other phones  at a click of a button and help with some code is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? could you show us some code? It will increase the chances of getting better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of services that will take your money and make this easier on you, but we've achieved this by attempting the major carriers (ie. 5555555555@txt.att.net for AT&T)

Its a workaround, but its free and simple to implement using standard SMTP stuff (GMail in this Example):

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
   Credentials = new NetworkCredential("fromuser@gmail.com", "pass"),
   EnableSsl = true
};
client.Send("fromuser@gmail.com", "5555555555@txt.att.net", "", "textbody");
client.Send("fromuser@gmail.com", "5555555555@vtext.com", "", "textbody");
client.Send("fromuser@gmail.com", "5555555555@txt.att.net", "", "textbody");
client.Send("fromuser@gmail.com", "5555555555@txt.att.net", "", "textbody");
...
```

Then you write code to monitor the email address inbox for failures, and mark those in the database, so the next time you send the text you know which carrier to use.

**One** comprehensive list  of carrierscan be found here:

http://martinfitzpatrick.name/list-of-email-to-sms-gateways/

And there are plenty of others

Comment: I want to send messages to mobiles not mail id bro.